# How to loop an operation through a series of values one of which is 0

Tags: r

I need to iterate an operation on a series of values using for loop. At the end the loop outputs a value for each input value except when input value is 0

I have provided values using both 0:10 and `c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` but the result is the same in both cases.

j

```
nk1<-as.integer()

jnk1<-as.numeric()

for (i in 0:10){
jnk1[i]<-100*i}

#Expected result: 
jnk1
0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000

#Obtained result:
jnk1
100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000
```

Comment: R is vectorized. You can simply do `100 *c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`

Comment: Arrays in R start at 1, not 0. Your loop is trying to set a `jnk1[0]` value which doens't work. Plus, you don't need a loop. You can just do `jnk1 <- 100*0:10`

Comment: arrays in `R` are one-based, not zero-based.

Comment: R's first index is 1; not 0. Therefore, the `jnk1[0]` does not exist. The first value stored is then `jnk1[1]`, which is in your case 100. To do what you want, you need to do it as following:

`for (i in 0:10){
jnk1[i+1]<-100*i}`
You can also do though` jnk1<- c(0:10)*100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `seq.int`, creating a sequence from 0 to 1000 by step 100 :

```
seq.int(0, 1000, 100)
[1]    0  100  200  300  400  500  600  700  800  900 1000
```